# How do I compare dates in one SQL table to a range defined in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one table holding events and dates:

```
 NAME  | DOB
 -------------------
 Adam  | 6/26/1999
 Barry | 7/18/2005
 Daniel| 1/18/1984
```

I have another table defining date ranges as either start or end times, each with a descriptive code:

```
 CODE      | DATE
 ---------------------
 YearStart| 6/28/2013
 YearEnd  | 8/14/2013
```

I am trying to write SQL that will find all Birthdates that fall between the start and end of the times described in the second table. **The YearStart will always be in June, and the YearEnd will always be in August.** My thought was to try:

```
 SELECT 
      u.Name
      CAST(MONTH(u.DOB) AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(DAY(u.DOB) AS varchar) as 'Birthdate',
      u.DOB as 'Birthday'
 FROM 
      Users u
 WHERE
      MONTH(DOB) = '7' OR
      (MONTH(DOB) = '6' AND DAY(DOB) >= DAY(SELECT d.Date FROM Dates d WHERE d.Code='YearStart')) OR
      (MONTH(DOB) = '8' AND DAY(DOB) <= DAY(SELECT d.Date FROM Dates d WHERE d.Code='YearEnd')))
 ORDER BY
      MONTH(DOB) ASC, DAY(DOB) ASC
```

But this doesn't pass, I'm guessing because there is no guarantee that the internal SELECT statement will return only one row, so cannot be parsed as a datetime. How do I actually accomplish this query?

Comment: What datatype is the `DOB` and `DATE` fields?

Comment: I recommend you to change `YearStart` and `YearEnd` to `Columns` instead of `Rows`

Comment: How do you distinguish a range if there might be multiple rows returned from your 2nd table?

Comment: @tommy_o both DOB and DATE are datetime

Comment: @EmmanuelRC I agree that this would be better, but I'm locked into a system that I didn't design and that table is extensively used in other places, so I'm unfortunately without that option

Comment: @GoatCO Each "Code" is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems strange and I still feel like we're missing a relevant piece of the requirements, but look at the following.  It seems from your description that the years are irrelevant and you want birthdays that fall between the given months/days.

```
SELECT 
    t1.Name, t1.DOB
FROM 
    t1
    JOIN t2 AS startDate ON (startDate.Code = 'YearStart')
    JOIN t2 AS endDate ON (endDate.Code = 'YearEnd')
WHERE 
    STUFF(CONVERT(varchar, t1.DOB, 112), 1, 4, '') BETWEEN 
        STUFF(CONVERT(varchar, startDate.[Date], 112), 1, 4, '')
        AND
        STUFF(CONVERT(varchar, endDate.[Date], 112), 1, 4, '')
```

Comment: This was what I needed. The WHERE clause makes sense, I'm just curious if someone could explain how the behavior of the FROM clause functions in plain english.

Comment: It JOINS the second table twice.  It then gives the two joined tables the aliases "startDate" and "endDate"

You would usually see the "ON" part of a JOIN referencing columns from each of the 2 tables being joined...

JOIN t2 ON (t1.Id = t2.Id)

... but in this case we limit the records by looking for the desired value in the Code column.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Joining to a table multiple times can be avoided using the pivot answer I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a PIVOT to get the years on the same row, like this.  This will return only 'Bob'

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE(
NAME VARCHAR(20),
DOB VARCHAR(10));

DECLARE @Dates TABLE(
CODE VARCHAR(20),
THEDATE VARCHAR(10));

INSERT @Names (NAME,DOB) VALUES ('Adam', '6/26/1999');
INSERT @Names (NAME,DOB) VALUES ('Daniel', '1/18/1984');
INSERT @Names (NAME,DOB) VALUES ('Bob', '7/1/2013');

INSERT @Dates (CODE,THEDATE) VALUES ('YearStart', '6/28/2013');
INSERT @Dates (CODE,THEDATE) VALUES ('YearEnd', '8/14/2013');

SELECT * FROM @Names;
SELECT * FROM @Dates;

SELECT n.*
FROM @Names AS n
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
            1 AS YearTypeId 
          , [YearStart]
          , [YearEnd]      
    FROM    ( SELECT    [CODE]
                      , THEDATE
              FROM      @Dates
            ) p PIVOT ( MIN(THEDATE)
                        FOR [CODE] 
                          IN ([YearStart],[YearEnd])
                      ) AS pvt) AS y
ON 
    n.DOB >= y.YearStart 
    AND n.DOB <= y.YearEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

From the last paragraph in your question, I am assuming that the Dates table have one YearStart and one YearEnd row for each year, correct? If so, your SQL query should include the year you are interrested in.

Also, even if "date" is not strictly speaking a reserved word for SQL Server (see [Reserved Keywords for Transact SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)), you should avoid using such column names since, for example, ODBC does not allow them.

But to do something with only the information that you have already provided, you could do something like this to get the birthday celebrants for the last year defined in Dates (providing there really is both a YearStart and YearEnd entry for that year):

```
SELECT DISTINCT <the rest as in your example>
 FROM  Users u
 WHERE u.DOB >= (SELECT max(d1.Date) FROM Dates d1 WHERE d1.Code = 'YearStart')
  AND  u.DOB <= (SELECT max(d2.Date) FROM Dates d2 WHERE d2.Code = 'YearEnd')
 ORDER BY u.DOB;
```

The main difference between the query above (which I have not tested - this is just to show the principle) and your post is that I trust the datetime type (or whichever variant of it that you have used in the database) to work as intended. What I mean by that is that the database engine is well aware (well, it *should* be) of which of two full dates is the earliest and the latest - you do not have to extract and compare their components separately.

/Bosse