# SQL Find Where Date Falls in Table Based on Date Range in Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, date

I'm trying to do something that I think is fairly simple in SQL.  I've looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682175/how-do-i-compare-dates-in-one-sql-table-to-a-range-defined-in-another-table), but I don't think it's quite the same as what I'm looking for (since I have no Code column). I have one table that looks like this (there are other columns, but they don't factor in to this question so I've omitted them for brevity):

```
TABLE T1

   ID  | CODE | DATE                 | ...
 ------------------------------------------
   0   |  A1  | 2013-01-17 00:00:00  | ...
   1   |  A1  | 2014-02-01 00:00:00  | ...
   2   |  B5  | 2014-06-30 00:00:00  | ...
   3   |  C1  | 2013-12-01 00:00:00  | ...
   4   |  B5  | 2012-04-20 00:00:00  | ...
```

Then in a separate table, I have information about those codes, like this:

```
TABLE T2

  STARTDATE           | ENDDATE             | CODE | DESCRIPTION     | ...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2012-01-01 00:00:00 | 2013-05-17 00:00:00 |  A1  | No room         | ...
  2013-05-17 00:00:00 | 2014-12-31 00:00:00 |  A1  | Not extra room  | ...
  2011-02-12 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |  B5  | Lights          | ...
  2014-01-01 00:00:00 | 2014-08-11 00:00:00 |  B5  | Lights (dim)    | ...
```

Basically, every code in `T1` will match up to a code in `T2`, but the description of that code changes based on the date.  So what I'm having trouble doing is finding the description in `T2` that corresponds to the code in `T1`, but it needs to be in the correct range `[STARTDATE, ENDDATE]`.

For example, `ID=0` in `T1` would have description "No room" while `ID=1` would have description "Not extra room", based on the date in `T1`.

**EDIT:** I really think I'm making this more difficult than it has to be.  Is it as simple as, in the `WHERE` clause, something like:

```
WHERE T1.DATE >= T2.STARTDATE and T1.DATE <= T2.ENDDATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking for query like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.code = t.code and t1.date >= t2.startdate and t1.date <= t2.enddate
...
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I edited my original post with that exact thing, haha.  I've been staring at documentation for other things all day and really really overcomplicated this problem.